# Get blob uploaded data with pure Perl

Tags: perl, blob, cgi

In Javascript, I am sending a blob using XHR by the following code:

```
var v=new FormData();
v.append("EFD",new Blob([...Uint8Array...]));

var h=new XMLHttpRequest();
h.setRequestHeader("Content-type","multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8");
h.open("POST","...url...");
h.send(v);
```

In the server, I have created in Perl the following function, that suppose to implement `CGI->param` and `CGI->upload`:

```
# QS (Query String) receive in argument string for single parameter or array of many required parameters.
# If string been supplied: Return the value of the parameter or undef if missing.
# If array been supplied, a hash will be returned with keys for param names and their corresponding values.
# If the first argument is undef, then return hash with ALL available parameters.
sub QS {
    my $b=$ENV{'QUERY_STRING'};
    if($ENV{'REQUEST_METHOD'} eq "POST") {
        read(STDIN,$b,$ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'}) or die "E100";
    }
    my $e=$_[0]; my $t=&AT($e); my $r={}; my @q=split(/&/,$b);
    my %p=(); if($t eq "A") { %p=map { $_=>1 } @{$e}; }
    foreach my $i(@q) {
        my ($k,$s)=split(/=/,$i); $s=~tr/+//; $s=~s/%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])/pack("C",hex($1))/eg;
        if($t eq "") { $r->{$k}=$s; }
        elsif($t eq "A") { if($p{$k}) { $r->{$k}=$s; } }
        elsif($k eq $_[0]) { return $s; }
    }
    return $r;
}

# AT is a function for determining type of an object, and also a quck way to distinguish between just a string and a number.
sub AT {
    if(!defined $_[0]) { return ""; } my $v=ref($_[0]);
    if($v eq "") { return ($_[0]*1 eq $_[0])?"N":"S"; }
    my $k={"ARRAY"=>"A","HASH"=>"H"};
    return $k->{$v}||$_[0]->{_obt}||$v;
}
```

So in the main program it will be called as:

```
my $EFD=&FW::QS("EFD"); # FW = The module name where QS and AT are.
```

When I issuing the POST from the client, the script in the server does not pop-up any errors, and does not terminates - it continues to run and run and run.... Endlessly.... Consuming 100% CPU time and 100% memory - without any explanation.

I have these in the beginning of the script, though:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;
```

but it still behave in such a way that I need to kill the script in order to terminate it...

Anyone know what I did wrong...? No infinite loop here, as far as I know... If I change the Blob to regular classic way of "...url...?EFD=dhglkhserkhgoi" then it works just fine, but I want a Blob....

Thanks a lot

Comment: Is there a reason you're re-implementing bits of CGI? The CGI module comes with Perl. How is `QS` called? What is the `AT` function? Could you throw some debugging print statements into your server to determine where it's hanging?

Comment: It is not obvious what is your task. It would be helpful to describe what you try to achieve and why you have chosen this path. Providing an information how content of the blob _generated_ (what it's content -- image, binary file, something else) would assist to understand your task.

Comment: CGI module been removed from the core since v5.22 - and the above is a way part of a new framework that claims to be 100% pure. Currently, as mentioned above, the script does not popup any error but just not terminating....

Comment: Does it matters for the content of the binary data in the Blob? It is just arbitrary object encoded into binary: Can be array or hash of strings mixed with numbers.

Comment: Content of binary can be anything, but by describing what you try to put into it -- may lead to an ideas of other ways to achieve same/similar result. For example why not to use already existing frameworks (Catalyst, Dancer 2, Mojo, Ruby on Rails, Hanami, Sinatra, Grape, Django, Flask, Tornado, Lavarel, ....).

Comment: I will be one of these in the future - without a need of special installation, so it can be used even under shared host by a free choice, no need to be preinstalled, but still can do a lot of stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `QS` function is only usable for `POST`s with an `application/x-www-urlencoded` body, which yours isn't.

Comment: Yes - I have checked my code, it has header of: 

------WebKitFormBoundaryBBH1ioJXZPKnr6Bf
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="EFD"; filename="blob"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

And the content is really binary.... Now: I have no other posting methods in my webapp, so it should be enough.... The QS method designed for regular POST/GET, but it will be rarely used in my web app, so I will modify it. Thank you